# Silverlight communication with existing WCF secured service

Tags: wcf, silverlight, single-sign-on

I’m very new to SL and was from ASP.NET and WPF back ground. I wish to ask couple of question which may be very basic for you guys... Please feel free to consider this and respond with sample code / Link.

Let me define my current situation.

I have an enterprise application in finance domain which is built in WPF, WCF and SQL 2008. All my smart client WPF communication routed through a distributed environment via 
WCF. It has customized behaviors, bindings, SSO etc.

Now my question is, I’m in process of building a POC in Silverlight to connect to the SQL server db via the same existing WCF service. Will that be possible? If so, how?

Here is my service end point sample which is being consumed by WPF smart client application

```
<endpoint address="http://my IP/Application/TestService" 
          binding="customBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="httpCompressionBinding"             
          contract="ITestService" 
          name="WSAddress" 
          behaviorConfiguration="FullyAuthenticatedNonSsoBehavior" 
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You (maybe) need to tune wcf configuration so SL can use it without problems (maybe create separate endpoint for SL clients without line of code). 
SL as WCF client has some restrictions (WS HTTP binding is not supported, NetTcpBinding with security not supported, some response modes too ... and others). But I use it (I've created service SL admin console) to access my WCF consumed by WPF via TCP. TCP binding in silverlight client is CustomBinding. Why not? One of WCF goals is interoperability. So it can handle many different client requests in heterogeneous network.